# HTML buttons, toggle when button clicked and toggle all other buttons (collapse info)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, toggle

I am new to HTML-CSS. I have created some buttons and I am able to click on them and they will display more information. However I also want that when a button is clicked all the other buttons 'collapse' the information they were showing. I have tried looking it up and played around with the code but haven't managed to do it. Would appreciate some help!

```js
function thirdP() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Project3");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
 function secondP() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Project2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function firstP() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Project1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="firstP">1st Project</button>
     <div id="Project1" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the first project...</div>
</ul>
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="secondP">2nd Project</button>
     <div id="Project2" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>
</ul>
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="thirdP">2nd Project</button>
     <div id="Project3" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>
```

I know that probably this is very inefficient as I am writing the same Javascript function for every button. I haven't been able to create a single function that would work for all id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On clicking the button simply loop through all the elements whose `id` starts with `Project` to set `display = "none"` by using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Then show only the `nextElementSibling` of the clicked button. Try the following:

```js
function project(btn) {
  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Project"]').forEach(div => div.style.display = "none");
  btn.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="project(this)">1st Project</button>
  <div id="Project1" style="display: none;" align="right">Information about the first project...</div>

</ul>

<ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="project(this)">2nd Project</button>
  <div id="Project2" style="display: none;" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>
</ul>

<ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="project(this)">3rd Project</button>
  <div id="Project3" style="display: none;" align="right">Information about the third project...</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for not toggling is brackets. You never used brackets for function in onclick.

**Example :** 
`onclick="firstP()"`

I modified your code. Once check it. You can use one function to manipulate toggle for all id's, for that you need to pass id variable to a function like i did.

```
<ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="firstP(1)">1st Project</button>
  <div id="Project1" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the first project...</div>

  <script>
  function firstP(elementId) {
      var x = document.getElementById('Project'+elementId);
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
  </ul>

  <ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="firstP(2)">2nd Project</button>
  <div id="Project2" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>

  <!-- <script>
  function secondP() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Project2");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script> -->
  </ul>

  <ul>
  <button class="button" onclick="firstP(3)">2nd Project</button>
  <div id="Project3" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>

  <!-- <script>
  function thirdP() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Project3");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script> -->
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this solution, there is many other. If you think this is helpful.. cheers :D

```js
function showDiv() {

  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".info-div");
  x.forEach(item => {
     item.style.display = 'none';
  });
  event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="showDiv()">1st Project</button>
     <div class="info-div" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the first project...</div>
</ul>
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="showDiv()">2nd Project</button>
     <div class="info-div" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the second project...</div>
</ul>
<ul>
     <button class="button" onclick="showDiv()">3rd Project</button>
     <div class="info-div" style="display:none" align="right">Information about the third project...</div>
```